# How to remove md5 from the URL file name

Tags: php

I want to change my site form : www.example.c*om/pictures/az12a322a1e54a6z5e46az

to : www.example.c*om/pictures/(picturename)

for example when I upload a picture that called ( rose ) on pictures path I want the link to become :

www.example.c*om/pictures/rose

when I remove ( md5 function), the link doesn't work!!!

the configuration file is

```
/**
 * Checks if isEnabledPdf()
 *
 * @return true/false
 */
public static function isEnabledPdf()
{
    if (class_exists('Imagick')) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Preapre PDF for thumbnail
 *
 * @param string $file the file to convert
 *
 * @return false | $image | default pdf placeholder if imagemagick fails (usually with pasword protected pdfs)
 */
public static function openPdf($file)
{
    if (!ImageServer::isEnabledPdf()) {
        return false;
    }
    $file = urldecode($file);

    try {
        $img = new Imagick($file.'[0]');
    }
    catch(ImagickException $e) {
        // echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        unset($e);
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg('vfm-admin/images/placeholder-pdf.jpg');
        return $image;
    }

    $img->setImageFormat('png');

    try {
        $str = $img->getImageBlob();
        $image = imagecreatefromstring($str);
    }
    catch(ImagickException $e) {
        // echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        unset($e);
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg('vfm-admin/images/placeholder-pdf.jpg');
    }
    return $image;
}

/**
 * Creates and returns a thumbnail image object from an image file
 *
 * @param string  $file   file to convert
 * @param boolean $inline thumbs or zoom
 *
 * @return null | $new_image
 */
public static function createThumbnail($file, $inline = false)
{

    $relative = $inline ? '../../' : '';
    $file = urldecode($file);
    $filepath = $relative.$file;
    $imageInfo = false;
    $ext = strtolower(Utils::getFileExtension($file));

    if ($inline == true) {
        // $thumbsize = SetUp::getConfig('inline_tw');
        $thumbsize = 420;

        $max_width = $thumbsize;
        $max_height = $thumbsize;
    } else {
        if (is_int(SetUp::getConfig('thumbnails_width'))) {
            $max_width = SetUp::getConfig('thumbnails_width');
        } else {
            $max_width = 760;
        }
        if (is_int(SetUp::getConfig('thumbnails_height'))) {
            $max_height = SetUp::getConfig('thumbnails_height');
        } else {
            $max_height = 800;
        }
    }

    if ($ext == 'pdf') {
        $image = ImageServer::openPdf($filepath);
    } else {
        $imageInfo = getimagesize($filepath);
        $image = ImageServer::openImage($filepath, $imageInfo);
    }
    if ($image == false) {
        return false;
    }

    $width = imagesx($image);
    $height = imagesy($image);
    $new_width = $max_width;
    $new_height = $max_height;

    // set background color for transparent images
    $bgR = 240;
    $bgG = 240;
    $bgB = 240;

    if ($inline == true) {

        // crop to square thumbnail
        if ($width > $height) {
            $y = 0;
            $x = ($width - $height) / 2;
            $smallestSide = $height;
        } else {
            $x = 0;
            $y = ($height - $width) / 2;
            $smallestSide = $width;
        }
        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
        $bgcolor = imagecolorallocate($thumb, $bgR, $bgG, $bgB);
        imagefilledrectangle($thumb, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $bgcolor);
        imagecopyresampled($thumb, $image, 0, 0, $x, $y, $new_width, $new_height, $smallestSide, $smallestSide);
    } else {

        // resize mantaining aspect ratio
        if (($width/$height) > ($new_width/$new_height)) {
            $new_height = $new_width * ($height / $width);
        } else {
            $new_width = $new_height * ($width / $height);
        }
        $new_width = ($new_width >= $width ? $width : $new_width);
        $new_height = ($new_height >= $height ? $height : $new_height);
        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
        $bgcolor = imagecolorallocate($thumb, $bgR, $bgG, $bgB);
        imagefilledrectangle($thumb, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $bgcolor);
        imagecopyresampled($thumb, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
    }

    // Rotate image if is jpeg with exif data
    if ($imageInfo && function_exists('exif_read_data') ) {
        if (isset($imageInfo['mime']) && $imageInfo['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
            $exif = exif_read_data($filepath);
            $thumb = ImageServer::correctRotation($thumb, $exif);
        }
    }
    return $thumb;
}

/**
 * Function for displaying the thumbnail.
 * Includes attempts at cacheing it so that generation is minimised.
 *
 * @param string  $file   file to convert
 * @param boolean $inline thumbs or zoom
 *
 * @return $image
 */
public static function showThumbnail($file, $inline = false)
{
    $relative = $inline ? '../' : 'vfm-admin/';
    $thumbsdir = $relative.'_content/thumbs';

    if (!is_dir($thumbsdir)) {
        if (!mkdir($thumbsdir, 0755)) {
            Utils::setError('error creating /_content/thumbs/ directory');
            return false;
        }
    }

    $md5name = md5($file);
    $thumbname = $inline ? $md5name.'.jpg' : $md5name.'';
    $thumbpath = $thumbsdir.'/'.$thumbname;

    if (!file_exists($thumbpath)) {
        $file = Utils::extraChars($file);
        $image = ImageServer::createThumbnail($file, $inline);

        $imageout = $image ? $image : imagecreatefromjpeg($relative.'images/placeholder.jpg');

        if ($imageout) {
            imagejpeg($imageout, $thumbpath, 80);
            imagedestroy($imageout);
        }
    }

    if ($inline) {
        return 'vfm-admin/_content/thumbs/'.$thumbname;
    } else {
        header('Location: '.$thumbpath);
        exit;
    }
}

/**
 * Open different types of image files
 *
 * @param string $file      the file to convert
 * @param array  $imageInfo getimagesize array
 *
 * @return $img
 */
public static function openImage($file, $imageInfo = false)
{
    if (!$imageInfo) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check the memory needed
    $memoryNeeded = (($imageInfo[0] * $imageInfo[1]) * $imageInfo['bits']);
    $memoryLimit = (strlen(ini_get('memory_limit')) > 0 ? ImageServer::returnBytes(ini_get('memory_limit')) : false);
    $lowmemory = false;
    $exif = false;

    // Try to set the needed memory_limit
    if ($memoryLimit && $memoryNeeded > $memoryLimit) {
        $lowmemory = true;
        $formatneeded = (round($memoryNeeded/1024/1024)+10).'M';
        if (ini_set('memory_limit', $formatneeded)) {
            $lowmemory = false;
        }
    }

    // Genereate thumbs
    if ($lowmemory === false) {
        switch ($imageInfo['mime']) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $img = imagecreatefromgif($file);
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            $img = imagecreatefrompng($file);
            break;
        default:
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            break;
        }
    } else {
        imagecreatefromjpeg('vfm-admin/images/placeholder.jpg');
    }
    return $img;
}

/**
 * Adjust image rotation
 *
 * @param obj   $imageResource the image to rotate
 * @param array $exif          the exif data
 *
 * @return converted size
 */
public static function correctRotation($imageResource, $exif = false) 
{
    $image = $imageResource;

    $rotate = false;
    $flip = false;

    if ($exif && function_exists('imagerotate') && !empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
        switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 3: // 180
        case 4: // 180 + flip horiz
            $rotate = 180;
            break;
        case 5: // -90 + flip horiz
        case 6: // -90
            $rotate = 270;
            break;
        case 7: // 90 + flip horiz
        case 8: // 90
            $rotate = 90;
            break;
        default:
            $rotate = false;
        }

        if (function_exists('imageflip')) {
            switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
            case 2: // flip horiz
            case 4: // 180 + flip horiz
            case 5: // -90 + flip horiz
            case 7: // 90 + flip horiz
                $flip = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($rotate) {
            try {
                $image = imagerotate($imageResource, $rotate, 0);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                unset($e);
            }
        }

        if ($flip === true) {
            try {
                imageflip($image, IMG_FLIP_HORIZONTAL);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                unset($e);
            }
        }
    }
    return $image;
}

/**
 * Convert M K G in bytes
 *
 * @param string $size_str original size
 *
 * @return converted size
 */
public static function returnBytes($size_str)
{
    switch (substr($size_str, -1)) {
    case 'M':
    case 'm':
        return (int)$size_str * 1048576;
    case 'K':
    case 'k':
        return (int)$size_str * 1024;
    case 'G':
    case 'g':
        return (int)$size_str * 1073741824;
    default:
        return $size_str;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you asked the original author how to adjust the script from him/her?

Comment: If you remove md5() then you might encounter conflict b/w files with same name. You sure that won't be an issue?

Comment: If you remove md5file you need to remove all uses as well

Comment: the solution is to change md5($file) by basename($file)

Answer (score 0):

the solution to replace this code

```
            $md5name = md5($file);
```

by this code

```
            $md5name = basename($file);
```